# Sum of freely chosen subset of $n$-tuple is divisible by $n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, divisibility

I am struggling with the following task:

Be $n \in N$ and $(a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n) \in \mathbb{Z}^n$. Prove that there is always $i, j \in \underline{n}$, with $i≤j$, so that $\sum_{k=i}^j a_k$ is divisible by n.

My first idea was to use a distinction of cases. In the first case a multiple of n is an element of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ so you could select the sum to be just this element so it would obviously be divisible.

In the second case, all elements of the tuple are the same, so that adding them all up will result in a multiple of $n$ once more, making it divisible.

I am lost however on what to do in the third case, where the two above are not true. I would truly appreciate your input.

Answer (score 4):

Some elements of $(a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n)$ may be different and it need not contain a multiple of $n$ of course. (it is chosen just randomly from $\mathbb{Z}^n$.)

You need a little trick to solve this problem in an easy way. Consider $n$ values
$$
a_1, a_1+a_2, a_1+a_2+a_3, \ldots , a_1+a_2 +\cdots a_n.
$$ If at least one of them is a multiple of $n$, it's okay. If not, what can be said about their remainders divided by $n$?

Comment: I think we have almost identical answers (+1).

Answer (score 2):

Using pigeonhole principle, let's look at all the remainders of
$$a_1 \pmod{n}$$
$$a_1+a_2\pmod{n}$$
$$a_1+a_2+a_3\pmod{n}$$
$$...$$
$$a_1+a_2+a_3+...+a_n\pmod{n}$$
If at least one is $0$, we are done.

If none is $0$, then at least $2$ will have the same value (there will be $n$ remainders, taking $n-1$ possible values within $\{1,...,n-1\}$, **pigeonhole principle**). E.g.
$$a_1+a_2+a_3+...+a_j \equiv a_1+a_2+a_3+...+a_i \pmod{n}$$
The remaining part is to subtract, assume $i<j$

$$(a_1+a_2+a_3+...+a_j)- (a_1+a_2+a_3+...+a_i)\equiv 0 \pmod{n}$$
or
$$a_{j+1}+a_{j+2}+a_{j+3}+...+a_i\equiv 0 \pmod{n}$$

Comment: This is very extensive and well written. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I understand how this works. However I have trouble to understand how you reach the conclusion, that "If none is 0, then at least 2 will have the same value". If this would be given the rest of your calculations fall into place.

Comment: @JulianGi recall [divisibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remainder#Integer_division), remainder is $0\leq r <n$. We excluded $0$ so $1\leq r <n$ or we have $n-1$ possible values from $1$ to $n-1$. The sequence constructed $a_1, a_1+a_2,...,a_1+a_2+...+a_n$ contains $n$ elements, taking the remainder of $\pmod{n}$ yields $n$ remainders, taking values from $1$ to $n-1$. There is no one to one mapping between $n$ remainders taking values from $\{1,2,...n-1\}$ and $\{1,2,...n-1\}$, so "at least 2 (remainders) will have the same value ...".

Comment: @rtybase That makes a lot of sense. Thank you very much.